# Difference between inorganic and organic semiconductors: electronic structure or configuration, or?

Tags: electronic-configuration, terminology, bond

Organic semiconductors differ from inorganic semiconductors. In organic semiconductors the molecules are held together by weak van der Waals interactions and in inorganic semiconductors by covalent bonds. So the bonds are different. How do you express the main difference between the twos? Is it the electronic structure or rather the electronic configuration, or something else?

Comment: The conjugated $\ce{\pi}$ electron in organic polymers is responsible for the conduction of electricity.